# multiple forms in jsf primefaces

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

I am developing a primefaces 5.2 application and using tomcat. I have a file upload component. For the file upload component to work, I changed the enctype. Later I decided to split the form into two. That's where my problems started. When I have two forms such as this

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
</h:form>

<h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</h:form>
```

does not work. Even the first form requests are not submitted anymore. If I take out the enctype from the second form, everything works.

I have looked at the data going across the network for the second form with and without the form-data. It looks like data is the same using Firebug.

Since it does not give me any error messages, I am kind of stuck. Where should I look? Thanks.

What's interesting is I add the enctype of form-data to the first form and remove from the second, things still work.

Comment: Symptoms described in question and answer are recognizable as when you nest forms in each other (which is illegal in HTML). Sure that you don't have e.g. another `<h:form>` in the master template which could wrap one or both forms?

Comment: Checked. My first page was search screen. For some reason, the second click searches the users. However edit user functionality causes a reload of the page. This only happens on IE 10... if I use IE 8, it works without issues. I am kinda at a loss. For now I will tell users to try Chrome. It's an internal web app so there should be no problem. I will try to nail the problem when I have more time during development. Also other than the invalid tag start message from IE console, I don't see any error messages.

Comment: If you can't tell if you wrote JSF code in such way that it produces valid HTML, run the w3 HTML validator.

Comment: I did but there are way too many problems with the generated html from primefaces/jsf. I refreshed cache and removed <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> . Not sure if that helped or it was the cache. It still needs an extra click once the page is loaded but seems to be ok after it. The dialogs seem to have a problem as well since they seem to not refresh properly. The update attribute works the second time again in IE 10. Not sure why.. IE 10 is not that important here since they are supposed to move to IE 11 but I am trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: One thing, is when it does not work, you think you clicked.. it posts an empty packet (there is no data associated with, no request parameters). Confirmed with fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fact that I have not added the primefaces filter. Now that I have added the filter to web.xml. My problem becomes why does it not work in IE 10 consistently. It works the first time, but does not work on subsequent refreshes.

I have not been able to figure it out yet. It seems if I change compatibility mode, the app starts working but after every page refresh (non-ajax), it goes back to a weird behaviour where first click does not work but second one does...Almost as if some javascript problem...

That's related to an IE problem/single sign on filter. Read more about it another question.